# Remote MySQL Connection Issues - Lost connection to MySQL server (110)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to access a MySQL database on server X from a php script on server Y.  Both are dedicated cPanel servers that I have root access to.  Here's what I've tried:

1. On server X I put the IP address of server Y in the "Additional MySQL Access Hosts" feature of WHM.
2. On server X I logged into the cPanel for the account hosting the database I'm trying to connect to and I entered server Y's IP on the "Remote Database Access Hosts" page.
3. On server X I whitelisted server Y's IP in the firewall and opened incoming/outgoing port 3306 TCP.
4. On server X I added server Y's IP address to the /etc/hosts.allow file

Despite all of these things I've tried, whenever I try to run the script on server Y I get the timeout message:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110
```

This is my PHP code:

```
$host = '123.456.789.0'; //server X's IP
$db = 'user_test';
$user = 'user_test';
$pass = 'password';

if(mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)){
    mysql_select_db($db);
}
else die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much of a help it will be, but try to open my.cnf and replace the bind-address setting (127.0.0.1 OR localhost) with your live server ip.

Comment: I just tried that and restarted MySQL but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted your hosting provider to see if they can help?

Is there a firewall on the linux machine you're connecting to?

Did you test your my.cnf file with 127.0.0.1 and localhost?

What version of MySQL are you running on both machines? Can you upgrade them?

Comment: I haven't contact my hosting company yet because I was trying to avoid it, but that may be the next step.  There is a firewall on the remote machine, but like I said I whitelisted the other server's IP and opened up port 3306.  I just tried the my.cnf hack and it had no effect either.  Both servers are running v5.1.62-cll